# Python Logging: Add custom level for TODO?

Tags: python, logging, pyqt5

While developing an application using PyQT5 I'm still trying  to find a workflow that works best for me. At the moment, I'm mostly working on the gui (to demo to client), leaving the back-end code for later, so I'm connecting the button signals to empty functions that I need to write later. Up until now, I've added `print('#TODO: xxx')` in each function that is empty. This gives me some feedback in the terminal as to how often certain functions are called and which to prioritize. This sort-of works for me.

At the same time I am using the `logging` module as it is intended to be used. It seems like I could add a new logging level and use the logging module for this purpose as well, something like this:

```py
def print_badge(self, pers: Person):
    # TODO: print_badge
    # print('#TODO: print badge') #<- not needed anymore
    self.log.TODO('print badge')
```

The logging documentation [seems to discourage](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#custom-levels) creating own logging levels though. Is there a *reason why I shouldn't do this* or *a better option?*

Comment: Logging level is an int value, so you can use any except ones from [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels) table. To add custom name associated with int level use [`addLevelName()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.addLevelName)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why it was recommended *not* to do this and if anyone had better options...

Comment: I'd never declare custom levels as it just causes confusion. Even more, I'd never print TODO messages in log, it's quite useless for user. You can use `DEBUG` level though, should fit.

Comment: I'd `raise NotImplementedError` personally

Comment: The thing is, this is just for me during development. I'd use `NotImplementedError` for things that might not get done before shipping to the client, but at the moment I'm just trying to find a good way of being reminded of all the things that aren't done yet while I'm testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why custom logging levels are discouraged in general is that people who configure logging have to take these levels into account - if multiple libraries did this with multiple levels, one might have to know all of the custom levels used by all of the libraries in use in order to configure logging a particular way. Of course the `logging` package allows you to do it for those cases where it might be really necessary - perhaps for an application and libraries which are self-contained and not public, so the question of configuring those libraries by someone else doesn't arise.

It seems that one could easily use the `DEBUG` level for your use case - just include `TODO` in the message itself, and one can grep logs for that just as easily as a custom level. Or you can have a logger called `TODO` to which you log these messages, and handle those in a separate handler/destination (e.g. a file `todo.log`).

Comment: Oh great! I hadn't thought about using a separate logger with its configuration...